# QGIS OpenLayers not working

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am an extreme neophyte with QGIS, so I maybe doing this all wrong. I have loaded the OpenLayers plugin as described in several online posts (and youtube video), and it is shown as listed in my plugins as installed (with the X mark). But, as shown in the youtube video, the plugin is not listed under the Plugins menu item, nor are any tools shown.

I am using QGIS Chugiak v2.4.0 on a 64-bit Windows machine.

Comment: So the problem is that you can't find the plugin? Have you checked under Web -> OpenLayers plugin?

Comment: I found the plugin and installed it, and checked it, but I cannot find the actual tools/buttons to click to load the interface.

Comment: Disregard. I found it under the "Web" menu item. This is different than all of the online user guides and youtube videos that are out there, making this very confusing indeed. Thanks.